# Do-while loop java explanation

Tags: java, syntax, do-while

I do not get a do-while loop in java and the syntax of it. Can someone please explain it? How is it written in various forms, and what is its structure and syntax.

Comment: If you search the internet there will be thousands of explanations to help you.

Comment: Start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### While Loop (Check then execute)

```
while(condition_is_true) {

    // do something here

}
```

This loop is executed only while the given condition is true. Simple enough. Checking first.

#### Do-while Loop (Execute then check)

```
do {

    // do something here

} while (condition_is_true);
```

This executes then it checks if the condition is true. As a result, this will loop at least once.

Comment: thank you, I will vote your answer up as soon as I can