# Prime Number test beginner Java

Tags: java

College assignment for testing a positive number (called num) is a Prime Number or not.
I must use a Do while loop
Ive attempted the code as follows but its failing the test

```
public class Primes {
public static main void (String args[]){
int num = 1;
int 2 = 0;
boolean flag = false;
do {
if (num%i == 1) {
flag = true;
break:
}
num ++

while (i<=num);
{
if (flag = true);
{
System.out.println (num + "is a prime number ");
}
else
{
System.out.prinln (num + "is not a prime number ");
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Two bugs in `if (flag = true);`  1) You are >>assigning<< a value to `flag`.  `=` should be `==`, or better still `if (flag)`.  2) The semicolon should not be there.  It makes the "then" part of the "if" statement an empty statement!!!

Comment: To ask a good question here, specify what is either happening that you don't expect or not happening that you do expect. Say what you have done to try to figure it out yourself. You are much more likely to get answers, and in not a few cases will figure it out yourself. If you do post a question and get answers, upvote any that are helpful, and check off one as the 'best earliest' answer.

Comment: Other bugs indicate that the code won't even compile.  And you have hard-wired `n` to be one.  And one is NOT a prime number ... by definition.

Comment: Unrelated, but proper formatting makes code much easier to read and think about.

Comment: Please edit the question to indent your code properly. How do you expect people to volunteer to help you if you won't make at least a little effort?

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) {`

Comment: ``int 2 = 1`` is improper java. You aren't allowed to redefine a literal value.

Comment: ``flag = true`` will always be true. ``=`` is used for assignment. It's safer to check a boolean condition with ``if (flag) {}`` because you can't accidentally assign the value rather than checking it.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Main function signature

it should be

```java
public static void main(String args[])
```

not

```java
public static main void (String args[])
```

### 2. you cannot start a variable name with a number

```java
int 2 = 0;
```

you probably mean

```java
int i = 0;
```

### 3. `do { ... } while(...);`

The format of a do while loop is

```java
do {
  something();
} while (condition);
```

### 4. Semicolon means end of statement

```java
while (condition); {
  something();
}
```

in this case `something()` is not in your while loop

### 5. Watch out for assignment in `if`

```java
if (flag = true)
```

this is assigning `flag` to `true`. And the condition is always true (since the resulting of the assignment is true).

### 6. Not `System.out.prinln`

It is `System.out.println`. Use an IDE.

### Final solution

```
public class Primes {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int num = 3;
        int i = 2;
        boolean flag = false;
        do {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        } while (i < num);
        if (!flag) {
            System.out.println(num + " is a prime number ");
        } else {
            System.out.println(num + " is not a prime number ");
        }
    }
}
```

I also fixed some logical problem such as

1. you should probably increment `i` instead of `num`,
2. `while (i < num)` instead of `while (i<=num)`, otherwise some (last) `i` always equals to `num`, making everything not a prime
3. a number is not a prime when flag is true. you should probably invert the `if` logic. Flag is true when you find something that is evenly divisible, meaning the number is not a prime.

There are better solutions, but I stick with your format.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of different issues:

Firstly, it should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
```

Second, your variable on line 4 doesn't have name.

Your format for your do while statement is also, not quite right.

Another poster has a good example of a do while loop here:
[Do-while loop java explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663628/do-while-loop-java-explanation)

Also, go over the rules for where semicolons should be placed.